# Microsoft Exchange Server port configuration

Tags: email, mail-server, microsoft-exchange

I'm trying to setup an exchange server in the following configuration:

Server can receive emails from outside (internet).
But in order to view the emails, or configure Outlook, require to be on the internal network [or VPN].

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any configuration files you can add to your post?

Comment: Currently I'm trying out just having the MX records on GoDaddy. And keeping the ports internal and not forwarded through NAT. I'll report back when I have any results.

Comment: I meant it would be helpful to add this information to your post so people understand better how to help you.